# Don't execute jQuery if div value is lower than £X.XX

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I have a script that triggers a click on a page element (building an A/B test and need to bypass a certain page):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery(".collectionTab").trigger('click');
    }, 0);
});
```

What I want to do is STOP this script from executing if the value within a div is below a certain value. I.e.

```
<div class="totalPrice">£19.99</div>
```

As the total price is below 20 I would then want to NOT exectute the script.

Can't seem to get anything to work as am just guessing, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by parsing the text of `.totalPrice` to a float and comparing it. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var price = parseFloat($('.totalPrice').text().substr(1));
    if (price >= 20) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(".collectionTab").trigger('click');
        }, 0); 
    }
});
```